# iOS URL Schemes issue

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, url-scheme, vk

I need 2 url schemes for my app. One for Facebook, one for VK (Russian social network).

Right now I set it this way:

[image]

Is it correct way or I need to create additional item in URL types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done seems correct. Though I haven't used VK before, I often do this to allow for Facebook and a custom URL scheme, usually based on the app's name.

For instance, I used two URL schemes here and can successfully open the app with both.

[image]

I sometimes use the URL scheme to determine when a call is *not* from Facebook.

```
if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"m*****"])
{
    ...
    return YES;
}
return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
```

Comment: ok, thank you. I will wait for other answers for 10 min. And then I will mark your answer as correct.